# Bluetooth settings are not retained

Tags: bluetooth, 23.04

Ubuntu 23.04
Bluetooth disabled. Once I had to enable it.
Before shutting down I disabled it again.
Now, on *every* reboot it always on. No matter how many times I disable it, it turns on again on the next reboot.

What is the right way to disable it until I turn it on again manually?
I'm not sure what other details you may need: please feel free to ask any further info.